# How to save the channel or context for later use in developing udp server using netty

Tags: udp, netty

I'm developing an UDP server using netty. My scenario is following:
1. client send message to server
2. server send response to client
3. User click a button and then server send a command to client.

In this scenario, the step 3 is not triggered by the client. So in the step 2, when got the message from the client, I need to save the channel and remote address for the usage of step 3. However, I tried many methods, and don't work.

The following is my code snippet.

```
public class EchoSeverHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

private ChannelHandlerContext privateCtx;
private InetSocketAddress address;
private Map<InetSocketAddress, DatagramChannel> allChannels = new HashedMap();


@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {


    ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) packet.copy().content();

    byte[] req = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];

    buf.readBytes(req);

    String body = new String(req, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

    System.out.println("received: " + body);

    address = packet.sender();

    DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) ctx.channel();
    allChannels.put(address, channel);
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setAddress(address);
    event.setContent("Four");

    ctx.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(
            Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Hello, timestamp is" + System.currentTimeMillis(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8), address)).sync();
}

public void sendMsg (String msg) throws InterruptedException {
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setAddress(address);
    event.setContent(msg);
    DatagramChannel channel = allChannels.get(address);
    channel.write(event);
}
```

}

The method sendMsg is used to send the command to client by the user. The method is triggered, but the command doesn't be sent. 
Also, I tried following ways and all don't work:
1. save ChannelHandlerContext instead of DatagramChannel.
2. use channel.bind() to bind the address again.

Is there anything I missed for this scenario? Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `channel.writeAndFlush(...)`.

Comment: And I verified that the channel doesn't need to be saved in the map. Only need to save one instance of channel and it can be applied to different clients.